# Adding Windows Phone 8 Tile functionality to Windows Phone OS 7.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to support the new Windows Phone tile functionality in my existing Windows Phone OS 7.1 application, using the [documentation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). However, I can't seem to create an IconicTile through reflection as it keeps giving me NullReferenceExceptions and AmbiguousMatchExceptions. Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void CreateIconicTile(Uri tileId, string title, int count, string wideContent1, string wideContent2, string wideContent3, Uri smallIconImage, Uri iconImage, Color backgroundColor)
{
    // Get the new IconicTileData type.
    Type iconicTileDataType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IconicTileData, Microsoft.Phone");

    // Get the ShellTile type so we can call the new version of "Update" that takes the new Tile templates.
    Type shellTileType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");

    // Get the constructor for the new IconicTileData class and assign it to our variable to hold the Tile properties.
    StandardTileData CreateTileData = new StandardTileData();

    // Set the properties.
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "Count", count);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "WideContent1", wideContent1);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "WideContent2", wideContent2);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "WideContent3", wideContent3);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "SmallIconImage", smallIconImage);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "IconImage", iconImage);
    SetProperty(CreateTileData, "BackgroundColor", backgroundColor);

    // Invoke the new version of ShellTile.Create.
    shellTileType.GetMethod("Create").Invoke(null, new Object[] { tileId, CreateTileData });
}
```

I also tried creating the tile using the Windows Phone OS 7.1 way (`ShellTile.Create(...)`) and then calling the `UpdateIconicTile` method via reflection as described in the MSDN documentation. But that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am checking the platform version to ensure this code only runs on Windows Phone 8 devices and I have added the necessary code to my manifest.

RESOLVED: Thanks to the answer given by Martin Suchan below, I was able to solve this problem. The problem was with my call to `Invoke(...)` missing some properties. Here is the new line I am using to actually create the tile:

```
shellTileType.GetMethod("Create", new Type[] { typeof(Uri), typeof(ShellTileData), typeof(bool) }).Invoke(null, new Object[] { tileId, CreateTileData, true });
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're missing the gating check to make sure it doesn't run on WP7.1. Why is that? Are you trying to run create WP8 tiles on WP7.x? Obviously that won't work since the APIs being invoked via reflection just aren't there on WP7.x.

Comment: Sorry Justin, I should have been more clear. I am doing this check. I have updated my question with this clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the library Mangopollo, that contains working wrapper for creation new tiles in WP7.1 apps when running on WP8?
http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did not end up using Mangopollo, but the source code they have on CodePlex led me to the solution. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that reflection is enabled across the code.

Iconic Tiles are only available for windows phone 8 therefore you can only put the code into a windows phone 7.1 project if you check the version

```
private static Version TargetedVersion = new Version(8, 0);
    public static bool IsTargetedVersion {get{
               return Environment.OSVersion.Version >=    TargetedVersion;}}
```

Now see if the bool IsTargetedVersion is true. Basically,

```
if(IsTargetedVersion){
      //iconic tile code
}
```

Thus only when a windows phone with compatible features (i.e. an wp8) runs your app then it will work.

Comment: You have to also edit the Manifest but i'm assuming you've done that. If not go through that MSDN article you posted again